# Smarty use foreach twice in template

Tags: arrays, foreach, smarty

I have a variable $res which stores some values from my database.
In my template i want to use this variable with a foreach multiple times like this:

```
        {foreach $res as $r}
        <h1>{$r.name}</h1>
        {/foreach}


        {foreach $res as $r}
        <h1>{$r.image1}</h1>
        {/foreach}
```

Only the first foreach is being displayed when the page is rendered. If i put the 2nd one on top that one is rendered. Also there are values for both $r.$
Am i missing something?

Regards
Steffem

Answer (score 0):

Did you try the smarty-way of declaring a foreach?

```
{foreach item=r from=$res}
```

Comment: Hey, that was the 2.x way of declaring it.
In 3.x it goes as i originally posted.

Anyway i figured out that it works when i establish the db connection the simple way and not with pdo.

Comment: Hello Steffen, thanks for clarification. You might want to post the solution as courtesy to other visitors.

Answer (score 0):

First i was using the way given in the smarty Example App:

```
// database object
  var $pdo = null;
  // smarty template object
  var $tpl = null;
  // error messages
  var $error = null;

  /* set database settings here! */
  // PDO database type
  var $dbtype = 'mysql';
  // PDO database name
  var $dbname = 'database';
  // PDO database host
  var $dbhost = 'localhost';
  // PDO database username
  var $dbuser = 'guestbook';
  // PDO database password
  var $dbpass = 'foobar';
```

However that didnt work with using foreach statement anywhere twice.
Now i do it the simple way:

```
mysql_connect("localhost", "username", "foobar") or die(mysql_error());
mysql_select_db("database") or die(mysql_error());
```

This works out for me and fixes the problem.
**However be warned:** Neither of these ways are really safe if you are building a serious web project. Im going to take care of this issue later when i am done building the other stuff. For development purposes im absolutely fine with it though.